# Refer to a key with dot notation, type is { [x: string]: string}

Tags: typescript

How can I refer to the properties of an object where the keys can be any string?

I would expect the compiler not to throw an error on the final line:

```
export type apple = { [x: string]: string }

export type pie = {
  fruit: apple;
}

let myPie: pie = {
  fruit: {
    appleVariety: 'Granny Smith'
  }
}

console.log(myPie.fruit.appleVariety);
```

Comment: You can cast to `any`:
`(<any>myPie.fruit).appleVariety`, but you lose any intellisense this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have an indexable object like you're using:

```
type apple = { [x: string]: string };
let a: apple = { appleVariety: 'Granny Smith' }
let variety = a['appleVariety'];
let something = a['something']; // no error even though it's undefined
```

Or specify the properties in the object:

```
type apple = { appleVariety: string };
let a: apple = { appleVariety: 'Granny Smith' }
let variety = a.appleVariety;
let something = a.something; // Error: Property 'something' does not exist on type '{ appleVariety: string; }'.
```

You can't mix the two.
The philosophy behind this is that if you know the property names then explicitly include them in your interface/type definition.
But if you just have a collection of properties in an object then the compiler won't check for the property name that is used, only the type.

Comment: Thanks for the succinct answer, that clears it up.  It's a good point: if I know the name of a property I will refer to, it should be in the definition too.